# Web API and Database link C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently new to Web APIs and how to work with them. My project consists of a web api that communicates with a DB through Business and Data layers.
First, i have managed to create a controller as show below:

```
using BusinessLayer;
using BusinessLayer.Models;

namespace ContactService.Controllers
{
public class ContactController : ApiController
{


   public void Post([FromBody] Contact contact)
   {

        Business bu = new Business();
        bu.getcontact(contact);

    }
  }
}
```

The getcontact function which has Contact as an object:

```
 public void getcontact(Contact c) 
    { 
        Data dal = new Data();
        dal.ExecuteView(c.Fname,ref c.Lname,ref c.Age,ref c.exist);
    }
```

which gives an error like:

A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter?

And the contact class is:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The business layer is connected to the datalayer that manages all sql queries through many functions like:

```
 public void Save(String fname,String lname,String age)
    {
        if (fname != "" && lname != "" && age != "")
        {
            Data connect = new Data();
            connect.OpenConnection();
            connect.ExecuteInsert(fname, lname, age, ref exist);

            if (exist)
                    MessageBox.Show("Name exists");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("User entered successfully");
                connect.CloseConnection();
                //connect.isTimer();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter all fields");
            }
    }
    public void Del(String fname)
    {
        if (fname != "")
        {
            Data connect = new Data();
            connect.OpenConnection();
            connect.ExecuteDelete(fname, ref exist);

            if (exist)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Record exists and Deleted");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Record doesnt exist!");
            connect.CloseConnection();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter first name!");

        }
    }

    public void View(String fname,ref string lname,ref string age)
    {
        if (fname != "")
        {
            Data connect = new Data();
            connect.OpenConnection();
            connect.ExecuteView(fname, ref lname, ref age, ref exist);
            tb1.Text = fname;
            tb2.Text = lname;
            tb3.Text = age;
            if (exist)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Infos displayed");
            }
            else

                MessageBox.Show("Name not found");
                connect.CloseConnection();
        }       
        else    
        {       
                MessageBox.Show("Enter first name!");
        }
    }
```

For example, ExecuteView looks like this:

```
public void ExecuteView(String Fname, ref String lname,ref String age,ref 
bool exist)
     {
         try
         {
             //using (var command = new SqlCommand("DisplayInfo", con))
             using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(c.connstr))
             {
                 if (db.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                     db.Open();

                 DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
                 param.Add("@Fname", Fname);
                 param.Add("@exist", dbType: DbType.Boolean, direction: 
  ParameterDirection.Output);
  SqlDbType.int,ParameterDirection.Output);
                 Client cl = new Client();
                 cl = con.Query<Client>("DisplayInfo", param, commandType: 
  CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();

                 Fname = cl.Fname;
                 lname = cl.Lname;
                 age = cl.Age.ToString();

                 exist = param.Get<bool>("@exist");

                 if (db.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                     db.Close();
             }
         }
```

My question is: After getting to the Business layer, what should i do to execute the datalayer functions through getcontact() function in the businesslayer? And how to execute GET/POST/DELETE?

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Small note, you shouldn't use `MessageBox` code in your DAL. The DAL should only work with your repository. If you want to present something to the user, this should be handled in the presentation layer.

Comment: Okay, thank you i will correct it in my code

Comment: From what I understand, you are asking for this?

`public void GetContact(Contact contact){ var dal = new DataAccess(); dal.View(contact.FirstName, ...); }`

If not, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I have edited the question with ExecuteView function that i'm trying to execute in the DataLayer. The above didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken your code and changed it a bit. There is a lot which can be improved, but this will get you started I think.

First your data access class, it should only do data access and if you want to do something with the results, return it back to the business layer. So no `void` method.

```
//DAL
public Client ExecuteView(String Fname, ref String lname, ref String age, ref bool exist)
{
    try
    {
        //using (var command = new SqlCommand("DisplayInfo", con))
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(c.connstr))
        {
            if (db.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                db.Open();

            DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
            param.Add("@Fname", Fname);
            param.Add("@exist", dbType: DbType.Boolean, direction:
                ParameterDirection.Output);
            SqlDbType.int, ParameterDirection.Output);
            var cl = new Client();
            cl = con.Query<Client>("DisplayInfo", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();

            exist = param.Get<bool>("@exist");

            if (db.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                db.Close();
            }
            return client;
        }
    }
```

Your business class just calls the data access class and prepares the parameters, if necessary.

```
//Business
public Client GetContact(Contact contact)
{
    var dataAccess = new DataAccess();
    var client = dataAccess.ExecuteView(contact.FirstName, ...)
    //Do some business logic, if you want.
    return client;
}
```

Only the presentation layer is left (your API) and can look like this.

```
//Presentation
using BusinessLayer;
using BusinessLayer.Models;
namespace ContactService.Controllers
{
    public class ContactController : ApiController
    {
        public void Post([FromBody] Contact contact)
        {
            Business bu = new Business();
            var client = bu.getcontact(contact);
            //Do something with the client, if you want.
            Fname = client.Fname;
            lname = client.Lname;
            age = client.Age.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Over here you can change the `Client` object to some kind of viewmodel which you want to return or change the values to a better representation for your client/api.

Just keep in mind every layer has its own responsibility and shouldn't do anything which doesn't fit this responsibility.

Note: In your code you are doing an `INSERT` and `SELECT` in the above method. To keep the code clean, this should be handled in two seperate calls. You should split the functionality in the data access class and combine the calls in the business class, something like this.

```
public Client GetContact(Contact contact)
{
    var dataAccess = new DataAccess();
    var contactIdentifier = dataAccess.CreateContact(contact.FirstName, ...);
    var client = dataAccess.GetContact(contactIdentifier);
    //Do some business logic, if you want.
    return client;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your work but I tried to implement this in my code but gives an error in the business layer:
1- dataAccess.ExecuteView(c.Fname, ref c.Lname, ref c.Age,ref c.exist);
2-return client;

Answer (score 0):

This is poorly structured anyways.you should create a manager class for each object you have in the datalayer. for ex you have contacts object create a class called ContactsManager and it should get all the functions to implement from a reusable Interface.

Fell free to read more about it:

[A Complete Introduction to the Data Layer](http://www.datalayerdoctor.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-the-data-layer-for-digital-marketers/)

Comment: Do you mean like this?
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

Comment: each object gets 2 classes one holds the props (Contact) and the other holds the functionality (ContactManager) and encapsulate your reusable CRUD operations for example in an interface for the manager classes to use

Comment: this may seem a little complicated if you're not familiar with generics this is the repository pattern  [Repository Pattern]: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/6254/repository-pattern#t=201708231242114642178